# how to provide forwarding video functionalitie in HTML5 video tag?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video, video.js

I am using video JS for customising the video tag. i could not found any tutorials about how to do forwarding option of video tag.

My Questions are:

1) why Video tag should not provide forwarding options by default ?

2) If Video tag does not provide forwarding option then how to achieve it ?

Answer (score 0):

Finally i got to know that it was not the problem with video tag it was problem with the server which does not support byte range requests. now i tested with other server by hosting video in it and it is working fine..